# What is the object Porter hands to Carter?

Tags: payback

Porter manages to beat up Carter's bodyguards. Shortly, he hands over some cigar-shaped object to Carter. What is it? What is its significance?

Answer (score 6):

It is a roll of pennies. It is used in a fashion like [this.](http://www.ehow.com/how_2157575_use-roll-quarters-self-defense.html) You can see that it is a roll of pennies around the 1:03:49 mark when the guard is searching him and asks what is in his left pocket.

Comment: Are you watching the Director's Cut? I wasn't, and there was no moment where the bodyguard asked anything about what was in the pocket.

Comment: Yes, I was watching the directors cut version.